# MySQL: 1:n relationship with auto increasing PK

Tags: mysql

I've two tables: `users` and `files`. A user can create files (1:n relationship).
When a user is deleted, all the user files refered to the user should be deleted, too. Deleting single files of a user should also be possible.

#### Try 1

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `salt` VARCHAR(33) NOT NULL,
  `user_group_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_u_user_group` FOREIGN KEY (`user_group_id`) REFERENCES `user_groups` (`user_group_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `user_file` (
    `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `user_file_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `content` JSON DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( `user_id`, `user_file_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_uf_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

The table `user_files` contains files of all users so the primary key have to be a composition of `user_id` and `user_file_id`.
This solution works for me but there is one problem: The `user_file_id` is not increased automatically (because it's not the primary key). But I do not want to know the `user_file_id` when inserting new files to the table.

`INSERT INTO user_files VALUES(1, ???, 'New file', default)`

The `default` keyword instead of ??? is not working here.

#### Try 2

Another solution I though of would be to create a new table `user_user_files` that merges the tables `users` and `user_files`.

```
CREATE TABLE `user_file` (
    `user_file_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `content` JSON DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_file_id`),
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `user_user_files`(
    `user_id` INT NOT NULL,
    `user_file_id` INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`user_id`, `user_file_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_uuf_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_uuf_user_file_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_file_id`) REFERENCES `user_files` (`user_file_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

With that I could create a trigger when inserting a new row into `user_files` and that trigger would add a new row to `user_user_files`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER after_user_insert
AFTER INSERT
ON user_files FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO `user_user_files` VALUES(NEW.user_file_id,default, default);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But is this possible when I want the following behavior?

- Delete all user files when the user is deleted
- Option to delete single user files from a user

#### Summary

So with try 1 there is the problem that the primary key is not increased automatically.
With try 2 I do not know if my desired behavior works with deleting / adding rows.

Comment: Why not using user_file_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT and use just that as pk?